# build HTML5 offline web applications with Java

Tags: java, html, offline-mode

I want to build HTML5 Offline Web Applications but want to code in pure Java. I have seen [Sencha GXT 3](http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/download) but I am unsure as it supports for offline cache HTML5 or not.

If you have any experience with HTML5 Offline Web Applications then please let me know which one is better.

More Detail:

I want to host this HTML5 app to a webserver. User browse this app and it downloads itself into user's mobile. With this app user can fill reports, report GPS coordinates, take snaps and save them in each separate folder in mobile device and when mobile connects to Internet it uploads all the data.

Since this is an HTML5 and deployed on some webserver, User with any mobile phone having a browser should use it. **Is this possible ???**

[GWT Mobile PhoneGap Showcase Android Market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gwtmobile.phonegap&hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [mgwt](http://www.m-gwt.com) it has an offline linker that works with any GWT project, see: http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/HTML5Manifest

Comment: I also want to snap pictures through mobile camera and save them in local storage and then upload them when connected with internet. Do you think this can provide me this type of support ?

Comment: mgwt works very well together with gwt-phonegap. With Phonegap you can use any device feature you like. Take a look at the videos on http://www.m-gwt.com

Comment: There is no help unfortunately to get started... :-(

Comment: There is no GWT getting started (because there are many good resources out there), but special things with mgwt are covered in the wiki: http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/GettingStarted